# Render an eloquent model in alpine?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, alpine.js

I'm trying to loop out a list of users from it's eloquent model, passed to the view from the controller with `User::all()`.

```
<div x-data="{ users: {{ $users }} }">
    <template x-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
        <div x-text="user.name"></div>
    </template>
</div>
```

But nothing is rendering - where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't you need to do `'{{! $users->toJson !}}'`?

Comment: is there an alpine error in the developer console?

Comment: You're trying to drop an Eloquent object into javascript. It needs to be converted to json.